# Change getElement from Id to Tag (body)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adapt [this](https://codepen.io/MAW/pen/KdmwMb) script on CodePen to work with the `body` tag instead of the `container` id.

I've modified this line:

```
TweenLite.set("#container",{perspective:600})
```

With this line:

```
TweenLite.set("body",{perspective:600})
```

This change seems to work, adding a "`perspective:600;`" to the `body` tag.

Then I replaced this line:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container"),   w = window.innerWidth , h = window.innerHeight;
```

With this line:

```
var container = document.getElementsByTagName("body"),  w = window.innerWidth , h = window.innerHeight;
```

I've checked SO and Google and while it seems that `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementById` is the correct way to do it, for some reason it isn't working.

**How can I correctly apply the change from id to tag** in order for the script to work?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69c0hvns/) for you to play with.

Comment: Just do `document.querySelector('body');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var container = document.querySelector('body');
```

Comment: Both solutions offered the same result. I think your solution is better but it's nice that now I learned both ways. However, both solutions have this unexpected behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/gxjy012g/ (the leaves fall just UNDER the image in the body, not on the whole screen).

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, it was CSS related. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName` **returns an array** of all the elements with the tag you specify.

In this case, it will just have one entry because you are looking for the body tag (there is only one element with the body tag). However, in other cases there might be more elements, e.g. you could also go for document.getElementsByTagName('p').

To select the first and in this case only element, go for:

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Comment: Tried both solutions from the answers and both offered the same unexpected behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/gxjy012g/ (the leaves fall just UNDER the image in the body, not on the whole screen).

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, it was CSS related. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did not try the whole thing since I just had a minute. Happy that you managed to fix it.